# Serial Port reads fine but assigned string has junk, C#

Tags: c#, textbox, gps, serial-port

I am trying to split the incoming data from a Serial Port, and update text boxes with subsequent data. I first see if a split on '$' is possible, and if the next word after splitting is "GPGGA". If yes, I would like to extract data from this sentence where ',' serves as the separator.
Now, as you see, I update the entire data read by the Serial Port first, and this works fine. The full sentence containing the "GPGGA" line is displayed. But after I split it, the part of the sentence that contains the "GPGGA" looks something like this"GPGGA,1\0\0\0\0\0..." when really the sentence that was just updated to the text box before was "GPGGA,160333,,,......". I am absolutely certain that there is a value after GPGGA in the sentence but when i try to look at it in the debug mode, the string 'ser_data', and hence its subsequent substrings all show the same junk. So, the final text box that I want to update inevitably ends up displaying just 1.

Could anyone tell me why this is happening, and how I can correct it. I need it urgently for my thesis work.

Thanks,
Brett

P.S: I've attached the code below.

```
private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] bData = null;
        bData = new byte[40];
        serialPort.Read(bData, 0, 40);
        string ser_data = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(bData);
        txtAck.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateTextAck), new object[] { ser_data });
        string[] str = null;
        str = new string[40];
        string[] str_ack = null;

        str = ser_data.Split('$');
        if (str.Length > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                string temp1 = null;
                temp1 = str[i];
                if (temp1.StartsWith("GPGGA"))
                {
                    string[] temp2 = null;
                    temp2 = temp1.Split(',');

                    StreamWriter objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Server.txt", true);

                    if (temp2.Length > 1)
                    {
                        string Time_GPS = temp2[1];
                        txtEasting.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateTextEast), new object[] { Time_GPS });
                        string text = "Time : " + Time_GPS;
                        // StreamWriter objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Server.txt", true);
                        objWriter.WriteLine(text);
                    }
                    if (temp2.Length > 2)
                    {
                        string Lat = temp2[2];
                        txtLatitude.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateTextLat), new object[] { Lat });
                        string text = " Latitude : " + Lat;
                        // StreamWriter objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Server.txt", true);
                        objWriter.WriteLine(text);
                    }
                    if (temp2.Length > 4)
                    {
                        string Long = temp2[4];
                        txtLongitude.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateTextLong), new object[] { Long });
                        string text = " Longitude : " + Long;
                        // StreamWriter objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Server.txt", true);
                        objWriter.WriteLine(text);
                    }
                    if (temp2.Length > 9)
                    {
                        string Alt = temp2[9];
                        txtNorthing.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateTextNorth), new object[] { Alt });
                        string text = " Altitude : " + Alt;
                        // StreamWriter objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Server.txt", true);
                        objWriter.WriteLine(text);
                    }
                    string Text = "." + '\n';
                    objWriter.WriteLine(Text);
                    objWriter.Close();

                    temp2 = null;
                    flag_status = 0;
                }
                temp1 = null;
            }
        }
        str = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

SerialPort.Read does not necessarily read the number of characters you ask for.

You need to save the return value, which is the number of characters read.

```
   // nBytesRead will be between 0 and 40, depending on how many bytes were waiting.
   int nBytesRead = serialPort.Read(bData, 0, 40); 
   // Only decode the number of bytes actually retrieved.
   string ser_data = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(bData, 0, nBytesRead);
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Could you please elaborate. How should I be doing that?

Comment: serialPort.Read returns you how many bytes it has read. If you use any bytes beyond this, they will be junk (zeros, or if you re-use the same buffer, fragments of longer messages that you received in the past)

Comment: Ok... I'll try what Ben has suggested. Thank you Ben & Jason.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed and majorly cleaned up.  This assumes two things: that your encoding is really UTF-8, and that your lines end with newline characters.

```
private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    serialPort.Encoding = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8;
    string ser_data = serialPort.ReadLine();
    txtAck.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateTextAck), new object[] { ser_data });

    string[] str = ser_data.Split(new char[] { '$' }, 2);
    if (str.Length > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            string temp1 = str[i];
            if (temp1.StartsWith("GPGGA"))
            {
                StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Server.txt", true);
                try
                {
                    string[] temp2 = temp1.Split(',');
                    if (temp2.Length > 1)
                    {
                        string Time_GPS = temp2[1];
                        txtEasting.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateTextEast), new object[] { Time_GPS });
                        string text = "Time : " + Time_GPS;
                        // StreamWriter objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Server.txt", true);
                        objWriter.WriteLine(text);
                    }
                    if (temp2.Length > 2)
                    {
                        string Lat = temp2[2];
                        txtLatitude.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateTextLat), new object[] { Lat });
                        string text = " Latitude : " + Lat;
                        // StreamWriter objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Server.txt", true);
                        objWriter.WriteLine(text);
                    }
                    if (temp2.Length > 4)
                    {
                        string Long = temp2[4];
                        txtLongitude.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateTextLong), new object[] { Long });
                        string text = " Longitude : " + Long;
                        // StreamWriter objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Server.txt", true);
                        objWriter.WriteLine(text);
                    }
                    if (temp2.Length > 9)
                    {
                        string Alt = temp2[9];
                        txtNorthing.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateTextNorth), new object[] { Alt });
                        string text = " Altitude : " + Alt;
                        // StreamWriter objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Server.txt", true);
                        objWriter.WriteLine(text);
                    }
                    objWriter.WriteLine(".\n");
                }
                finally
                {
                    objWriter.Close();
                }

                flag_status = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```